# I am not getting full code coverage in my test class, is it because test data isn't setup correctly?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I'm new to Apex and have been working on a class as a training excersize. The invocable method works as expected when called from a flow but I'm having trouble getting the proper code coverage. I believe it's an issue with the test data I'm attempting to pass but I'm not sure how to correct it. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Here is the class

```
global class UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag implements queueable {
    
    InvocableVariables[] request;
    public UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag(InvocableVariables[] request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    //Invocable method called from flow
    @InvocableMethod    
    public static void UpdateIntegrationFlag(List <InvocableVariables> request){
        System.enqueueJob(new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag(request));
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
        //invocable variables
        List<Project_Order__c> recordIDs = request[0].recordIDs;

        try {
            //Create list of Project Requests based on input of recordIDs
            for( List<Project_Order__c> projectRequests : [Select Id from Project_Order__c where ID IN : recordIDs]){
                    //Create an empty list of Project Requests
                    List<Project_Order__c> requestsToUpdate = new List<Project_Order__c>();
                    //For each project request in the list set bulk status to Pending
                    for(Project_Order__c projectRequest : projectRequests){
                        Project_Order__c req = new Project_order__c();
                        req.Id = projectRequest.Id;
                        req.Bulk_Approval_Process_Status__c = 'Pending';
                        //Add to list
                        requestsToUpdate.add(req);
                    }
                    //Update the records 
                    update(requestsToUpdate);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            system.debug('Exception has occured' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }    
    global class InvocableVariables{
     
        //List of record IDs to process
        @InvocableVariable public List <Project_Order__c> recordIDs;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@istest
public class UpdProjReqIntFlag_Test {
    
    @isTest
    public static void runTest() {
         Test.startTest();
        UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables variables1 = new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables();
        List <Project_Order__c> projectRequestIDs = [Select ID from Project_Order__c];
        variables1.recordIDs = projectRequestIDs;
        
        UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables[] variables = new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables[]{};
            variables.add(variables1);
        UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.UpdateIntegrationFlag(variables);
        
      
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend very strongly you remove your `try`/`catch` block if you are not going to put any error handling logic in place.

Comment: Also see the Creating Test Data section of this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests in Salesforce runs in isolated environment without any of existing dataset (for right reasons).

So in your test you need to first create data for it to be available in main code so before this test code,

```
        List <Project_Order__c> projectRequestIDs = [Select ID from Project_Order__c];
        variables1.recordIDs = projectRequestIDs;
```

you need to insert records into `Project_Order__c`